# Working with square roots

Tags: limits, summation, radicals, riemann-sum

I'm asking for methods on working with and dealing with square roots in algebra. Numerous times square roots have been the bane of my existence and are usually difficult to get around.

E.g. the other day, I was working on finding the distance between the point $x=-1$ and $x=1$ on the curve $x^2$, whilst tracing the path of the curve (not the straight distance). I eventually established that the distance can be given by:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{n^2} \sqrt{16i^2+16in-16i+5n^2-8n+4}$$

Though I was unable to evaluate or even "play" with it due to the square root halting any of my attempts at evaluating the sum.

The square roots basically stop me in my tracks from even trying to play around with the question.

Are there any methods of getting rid of square roots, or at least making it significantly easier to deal with?

Comment: Is this an actual problem you came across or just a random one you've made up?

Comment: This looks like a *calculus* (Riemann sum) problem, not algebra-precalculus.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll retag the problem @BarryCipra

Comment: It's one that I've come across when doing work on limits and summation @Wojowu

Comment: "stop me in my tracks from even trying to play around with the question"

Don't let difficulties stop you from playing around with the question.  It would help the community better help you if you tried to describe what exactly about the square roots that gives you trouble.

The evaluation you posted looks hard, whether one is comfortable with square roots or not.  Looks like it would easier to evaluate as an integral.  If the point of the problem is to compute Riemann sums *in order to learn integrals*, please give more context in which this problem arose.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{2\sqrt{16k^2+16nk-16k+5n^2-8n+4}}{n^2} &=
  \frac{2}{n} \sqrt{5+\frac{16k-8}{n}+\frac{4(2k-1)^2}{n^2}} \\ &=
  \frac{2}{n}
  \sqrt{5+16\left( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \right)+
  16\left( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \right)^2} \\
\end{align*}

The Riemann sum is mid-point rule of:

> $$\int_{0}^{1} 2\sqrt{5+16x+16x^2} dx=
> \frac{6\sqrt{37}-2\sqrt{5}+\sinh^{-1}6-\sinh^{-1}2}{4}$$